# How it works MaterialDatePicker in Android?

Tags: android, kotlin, datepicker, material-components-android, materialdatepicker

I have some doubts about how it works the Calendar library in Android.

I have implemented a listener to get the selected date in the MaterialDatePicker. With the method `addOnPositiveButtonClickListener`, I get the date selected in milliseconds but I need to transform these milliseconds to a Date object, BUT! whenever I transform this millisecond to a Date object, I am not getting the right value.

For example, if I select **03/24/2021**, when I create a new Date object with the correspondent millisecond I get the next Date -> **03/23/2021**.

I am trying different solutions I find in different posts but no one works fine for me.

I am trying to use Calendar but is not working properly either.

```kotlin
fun Long.toDate() : Date {
 val calendar = Calendar.getInstance(TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC"))
 calendar.timeInMillis = this // calendar.time.time = this
 return calendar.time
 }
```

and also try it out with different timeZone

```kotlin
fun Long.toDate() : Date {
 val calendar = Calendar.getInstance(TimeZone.getDefault())
 calendar.timeInMillis = this // calendar.time.time = this
 return calendar.time
 }
```

I have also try to save the millisecond on my Calendar instance with `calendar.time.time` but also is not working for me.

It is so curious because if I set the next values on my device:

- Time zone in **New Zealand (GMT+13:45)** at **10:00 AM**,
- I select **03/02/2021**, so should return the same date.
- For this specific example is working fine (I am in Madrid, Spain GMT+01:00) and is returning the date **03/02/2021**.

If it was working bad, should returns 02/02/2021, but for this timeZone is working fine.

But, if I change my device values to:

- Time zone to **Colombia (GMT-05:00)** and I set my device time to **10:00 PM**.
- I select the same date, **03/02/2021**, it should return the same date.
- In this case, is returning me the day before, **03/01/2021**.

Why MaterialDatePicker is working so bad and how can I fix that without doing so badly tricky code?

I saw it can be fixed used SimpleDateformat, but I would like to keep the timeZone and do it a good way, or at least the best way...

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Avoid using the Date and Calendar classes. They are considered obsolete in Java because there are a number of issues that make them difficult and error-prone to work with. Use LocalDateTime and ZonedDateTime instead.

Comment: I know @Tenfour04 but for this project, I am not able to use these libraries so I need to find a solution using `java.util` libraries.

Comment: Hello. I have the same problem, did you find a solution for this and can you help me?